# Best practice while writing an adapter in java

Tags: java, adapter

I am trying to write an adapter. I have almost 50 attributes which I'm trying to adapt from one class to another.

My code looks like:

```
public static Type2 getType2(Type1 type1)
{
...

  if(!StringUtils.isEmpty(type1.getAttribute1()) {
     type2.setAttribute1( type1.getAttribute1() );
  }
  // and so on for all the 50 attributes
...
}
```

Is there a better way to write this adapter method?

Comment: Wouldn't an adapter reflect live changes in `Type1`? This looks more like a bean copy operation.

Comment: Best practice is not to have 50 attributes. Also, try Dozer the reflective bean copier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a generic way to copy attributes from one instance to antoher:

```
public static <T> T copy(T source, T target) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
    for ( Field f : target.getClass().getDeclaredFields() ) {
        f.setAccessible( true );
        Object o = f.get( source );
        f.set( target, o);
    }
    return target;
}
```

Comment: Better yet with property access and checking that both objects have the same property (name and type), the setter exists, etc. Declared fields is a bit risky

Comment: What about collections ?

Comment: Can I exclude some attribute like serialVersionId ?

Comment: @KevindraSingh you could test the field for static declaration Modifier.isStatic(field.getModifiers() and exclude it or declare those fields as transient e.g. 'Modifier.isTransient(field.getModifiers());'

Answer (score 2):

You might consider using [Apache Commons BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/) if attribute names match.

If no type conversion is needed, you could use [`PropertyUtils.copyProperties()`](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/PropertyUtils.html#copyProperties%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29):

```
public static Type2 getType2(Type1 type1) {
    Type2 type2 = new Type2();
    org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils.copyProperties(type2, type1);
    return type2;
}
```

If type conversion is needed, use [`BeanUtils.copyProperties()`](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html#copyProperties%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29) instead.